# How to expose statistics like a filter buttons

Tags: website-design, filter, controls

Basically I have a pane with some basic statistic. It shows how many elements have been added, removed or changed and I would like to use it also a buttons to turn on and off filters. But unfortunately I have no idea how to do it in appropriate way. Can someone take a look and propose any solution?

[image]

Comment: I'm wondering why you'd want to show the statistics to the user who is turning the filters on and off. What does that information help them do?

Comment: I think the only appropriate way for this is **don't do it**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a button with counter:

[image: button with counter]

<sub>*Source [tailwindcomponents.com](https://tailwindcomponents.com/component/button-with-counter)*</sub>